# How to strip off the dot from second columns data of file using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, shell, pattern-matching

I want to strip off the `dot(.)` from the second column of the file and print the pattern before the `dot(.)` Ex: `a15-ap-99995.wma.ibm.com`, In this pattern it has to display  only `a15-ap-99995` from the file `sample.txt`.

Here is my try :

```
 $string =~ s/[\/\s>.(].*//;
 awk -F\\| '$string  print \$2}' 'sample.txt'
```

Sample.txt contains following data :

```
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw1.boigroup.net|10014
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw2.boigroup.net|10015
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw3.boigroup.net|10013
```

Desired out put should be :

```
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw1|10014 
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw2|10015 
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw3|10013
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Desired out put should be :                    BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw1|10014
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw2|10015
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw3|10013                                                                It should stripoff the second column data after .appears

Comment: You could use: `$subject =~ s/\..*?\|/|/g;`  But this is not limited to the second column.

Comment: I have edited your output into your question. It is much clearer to to this than put it in the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;



open my $fh, '<', 'filename' or die "unable to open file: $! \n"; 
while(<$fh>){
#chomp;
my @array=split(/\|/);
$array[1]=~ s/\.(.*)//g;
print join('|',@array);
}

close($fh);
```

Output:

```
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw1|10014
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw2|10015
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw3|10013
```

Redirect output to file in one-liner reads from file1 writes to file2:

```
perl -lne '@string=split(/\|/,$_);$string[1]=~ s/\.(.*)//g;print join("|" ,@string);' file1 > file2
```

Comment: It is displaying in console, It has to reflect on original file or write into another file.. Please  modify the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

Now that you have explained your requirement better, this solution will do as you ask

```
perl -pe's/ \| [^.|]+ \K [^|]* //x' sample.txt
```

This matches everything between the first and second pipe characters, and removes everything after and including the first dot

---

You can do it this way. The regex just captures all characters that aren't a dot immediately after the first pipe character

```
perl -ne'print /\|([^.]+)/' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my ($thing) = m/\|(\w+)\./;
    print $thing, "\n";
}
```

Given your input data outputs:

```
youghalsw1
youghalsw2
youghalsw3
```

Based on your updated comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my @stuff = split /\|/;
    $stuff[1] =~ s,\..*,,g;
    print join ("|", @stuff );
}
```

Gives:

```
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw1|10014
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw2|10015
BOI_TESTFEED|youghalsw3|10013
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged as "shell" the easier way to do it in a one-liner is:

```
cut -d'|' -f2 sample.txt | cut -d'.' -f1
```

The first cut command splits the text using | as the delimiter and returned the second column. The second cut command splits the text using the dot as the delimiter and returns the first column.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, But it has to replace the data in file itself, as of now it is displaying in console..Please tell me the solution

Comment: Redirect the output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F'\|' -ae'$F[1]=~s/\..*//;print join"|",@F'
```